# What is DWASMod.dll?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, visual-studio-2015, profiling

When I do remote profile my web application with VS2015 and see the results, I found a lot of this `DWASMod.dll` consuming my resources.

I searched about this dll and couldn't find any resource talk about it. Could someone explain what is this dll coming from ?

[image]

Comment: Hi @Mohamed - same here. Are you running also on Azure or does this also happen on normal IIS?

Comment: Yes exactly Dirk , I am running on Azure. Could not find why!.

Comment: Thanks. My whole application was not running anymore. When I did a redeploy it did seem to fix it for me.. still wondering what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

It is a dll file that Azure needs to work. Your application will fail if it is deleted or replaced.